# PagedList - a way to use not with the whole collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I've got simple action in which I make a request to  web service to get a LIST<> of articles for specific group.

Then using pagedList (and specifying the desired page and page number) of course I specify the subset of that list I want to take. The problem is : the article for specific group can be thousand for example - and getting the info for all of them from the web service takes a lot of time and even sometimes crushes (when the articles are above 1000)

Is there a way to get the articles only for the specific page and still to use pagedList because I see that  unfortunately we have to  call ToPagedList method for the whole collection.

```
public virtual ActionResult ImportShow(String id, int? menuID, string articlegroupID, string menuforHistory,int? counter,int?page,int? pageSize,string articleDescr, int?  ArticleID)
        {



                List<WebServiceBeaMenu> standartList = ebServiceBea.GetArticle(Convert.ToInt32(menuID), articlegroupID, "", articleDescr);
                IPagedList<WebServiceBeaMenu> p_ProductsShow = standartList.ToPagedList(actualpage,actualPageSize);

                p_GroupMenu.ProductMenu = p_ProductsShow;
                p_GroupMenu.MenuHistory = p_GetMenuHistory.ToList();
                p_GroupMenu.MenuLeft = p_GetMenuLeft.ToList();
                return PartialView("ImportShow", p_GroupMenu);                 
            }
        }
```

here is my view

```
@model  MvcBeaWeb.GroupMenu



        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ProductMenu.Count; i++)
        {

        <div>
            var item = Model.ProductMenu[i];



            @Html.PagedListPager(Model.ProductMenu, page => Url.Action("ImportShow", new { id = Model.LanguageName, menuID = @Session["men"], articlegroupID = Session["article"], articleDescr = Session["articleDescr"], pageSize = Session["pageSize"], page }))

    </div>
```

Comment: I don't think that it is possible because pagelist act on the entire list. What you could do is change your call to the database to bring only the set of article that you want to show

Comment: If you are using ef or linq2sql then you can return an IQueryable and do a pagedlist over that. This will make sure not to select everything first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite `.GetArticle()` Or replace it with whith somethink like `.GetPagedArticle()` if you have access to WebService. This methid should have all paging params. That's the only way i think.
Your `.GetArticle()` method should return object like this:

```
public class Set<T>
{
    public Set()
    {
        Elements = new List<T>();
    }

    public Set(List<T> elements, int rowsAll)
    {
        Elements = elements;
        RowsAll = rowsAll;
    }

    public Set(List<T> elements, int rowsOnPage, int pageSelected, int rowsAll)
    {
        Elements = elements;
        PageSelected = pageSelected;
        RowsOnPage = rowsOnPage;
        RowsAll = rowsAll;
        PagesAll = (rowsAll % RowsOnPage == 0) ? rowsAll / RowsOnPage : rowsAll / RowsOnPage + 1; ;
    }
    public int RowsOnPage { get; set; }
    public List<T> Elements { get; set; }
    public int? RowsAll { get; set; }
    public int PageSelected { get; set; }
    public int PagesAll { get; set; }
}
```

Where `Elements`  should be not all elements, but only paged one.

Comment: OK for GetArticle - I will get only get the articles for that page List<WebServiceBeaMenu> standartList = ebServiceBea.GetArticle(Convert.ToInt32(menuID), articlegroupID, "", articleDescr);   But then TopagedList wants a whole collection with all products (i suppose this way it determines the pages and its logical)and I don't have such list
                IPagedList<WebServiceBeaMenu> p_ProductsShow = standartList.ToPagedList(actualpage,actualPageSize);

Comment: I don't get this comment. What i mean is that you should pass `actualpage` and `actualPageSize` parametrs into `GetArticle()` method. And do your pagination there - at WebService. If you can change this method and do it right it will help you.  Another posybility that @Jamie mention in his comment is that you can get from `GetArticle()` not `List`, but `IQueryable` collection and work not with all items but with Query in your `ToPagedList()` method

Comment: Ok I pass actualpage and actualPageSize parameters into GetArticle() method. and this means that for example I will get the info for ten articles out of 100 for example. What I ask is how pagedList will know that the total number of articles is 100 so it can draw the pages for example

Comment: Ah, now i get it. You should use class that have field `TotalRows` and collection an current paged rows. I update the answer with example of what i using for this purpose in my projects.

Comment: Thank you ; I came up with the same solution.I think it's the only one